# Using GeoPandas, Shapely and Fiona to "select" state from shapefile, save it and display it?

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas, fiona

I have the usual US census states shapefile for the 48 contiguous states. I am trying to select a state of interest from that shapefile then save that shapefile and display. I want to use GeoPandas, Shapely, Fiona to do this.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: GeoPandas use Shapely and Fiona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without more info but like this:

```
import geopandas as gpd

states = gpd.read_file(path_to_shape)

#select alaska if column name is "State"
ak = states[states['State'] == 'Alaska'])

#plot
ak.plot()

#save
ak.to_file(driver = 'ESRI Shapefile', filename = out_path)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Only thing I am trying to do now is created an outpath to my desktop. Not sure what to_file(out_path) means exactly. I created a variable called out_path like so: out_path = r"C:\Users\new\Desktop\selection_state.shp"....and then at the end of that code snippet I wrote: selection.to_file(out_path). Gives me a RuntimeError and says Failed to open C:\Users\new\Desktop\selection_state.shp

Comment: try `selection.to_file(driver = 'ESRI Shapefile', filename = out_path)`, I suggest you read http://geopandas.org/ as all your questions are answered in the documentation

Comment: If it's not asking too much. I have a related question. Would this be correct way to reproject that shapefile data to another projection? ak.crs = ({'init' :'epsg:3395'}), I want to put it in the best UTM but I don't think GeoPandas offers the option to input UTM projections like for example UTM 10 for California.

Comment: Everything has an EPSG, http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-10n/ is the one you want.  What you have listed there is defining the projection, be careful that you don't actually need to reproject which would be `ak = ak.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3395'})`, once again, this is in the documentation, http://geopandas.org/projections.html, please read.

Comment: Thanks once more. What I have has defined the projection, that means that my California shapefile is not in epsg: 3395 projection? Is defining the projection the same thing as reprojecting the shapefile?

Comment: No, when you read in your shapefile type `shape.crs` and what does it say? if nothing then you define it, if it says something then re-project it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm wondering if the line of code: ak = ak.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3395'}) would reproject the shapefile. I don't know if it's that a lot of projections look the same but when I write that line of code, save it, then display it, it looks identical to the previous shapefile that was in a different projection.

Comment: in the previous example type `ak.crs`, if you have a projection it will list it and then you can re-project.  If `ak.crs` is empty then you need to go figure out what your projection is. Yes `ak = ak.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3395'})` willl re-project

Comment: And if it has a projection already, by writing that line of code it effectively replaces the previous projection thereby reprojecting it in a different crs?

Comment: Just look at ak.crs again to see if it worked....

Comment: Ok, just wanted to be 100% sure. Thank you!